# IIS 7.5 Global URL Rewrite for no WWW

Tags: iis, iis-7, rewrite

Is there anyway to modify the applicationHost.config file so that all sites in IIS redirect from http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in IIS7.5 the way to do this is with URL Rewrite.  You have a lot of flexibility there. Check out [week 8 in this series](http://dotnetslackers.com/projects/LearnIIS7/).